# What causes a blocky texture pattern on models

Tags: libgdx, blender

I have been playing with some shaders and materials included in Libgdx demos, and I noticed that models which I've created for my game have a strange issue. I have created them in blender and UV unwrapped. What could be causing this? Is it because I used material with a texture which was not prepared for this model or botched UV unwrapping on my part?

[image]

I haven't seen the problem with models included with the demo (e.g. a teapot and the blender's Suzanne model)

Comment: Try to flip the y coordinate of the texture.

Comment: This mesh seems to be using flat shading and you probably want an interpolated one (Gouraud/Phong/etc.?).

Comment: @kolenda Yes, this is using Phong shader, but I'm not sure what you mean about the mesh using flat shading. I'm quite new to using blender

Comment: I mean that the rendering result depends not only on your shader, but also the mesh itself and how its normals are created. In your mesh each quad have its own normal, constant for entire quad so even using Phong shader each quad will look flat. What you need is to compute vertex normals to smooth this out. I don't know Blender (I could help you with 3ds) but those links may help you:  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/smoothing.html  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges